# Can't run Linux with home partition on removable hdd

Tags: boot, manjaro, external-hdd

I have a Linux installation with boot partition on internal laptop ssd and home partition on an external removable hdd. Since the first time I removed the HDD and booted Linux, I am unable to  make Manjaro run again.

It says "a launch job is running for /dev/disk/by-uuid/[id], reach timeout and then fails, being unable to solve dependencies for home and fsck. Then it asks for root password or ctrl +d. I give it root password but It doesn't make any progress.

Any fix?

Comment: I do not know if `blkid` is available in Manjaro's emergency mode. If it is, does it list list the external HDD? What does `dmesg` say in regard to the external HDD?

Answer (score 0):

You should give the manjaro systemd back the hdd with the home partition. Probably the UUID is in /etc/fstab, and that partition is now offline.

This is a big and a small thing at once. Do you have a reason for mounting `/home` externally? Otherwise it is quite standard to keep home on "root". Not `/root`, but `/`.

The failure is dramatic, but because "home" is missing, it is no wonder.

Comment: I have plugged the HDD again but I can't make Manjaro recognize it again and I keep being stuck on emergency mode. Main reason to keep home partition on external HDD is the fact that the on-board laptop SSD lacks space to keep both Windows and Manjaro on it

Comment: @EagleOne Can you just somehow filter out some important messages? I dont know manjaro, and from the distance it's kinda difficult. I always follow the error messages --- you have systemd?

Comment: @EagleOne ...and describe in three words how you dual boot. You have not done anything _drastic_ with the external HDD, like reformatting or changing partition types? I mean that partition's UUID match the /home entry in /etc/fstab? If yes and it stiill dont work we have a problem...unless you find that decisive error message!